# Relation between the Wronskian and Linearly independence of functions

Tags: functions, derivatives, determinant

How do we prove the following statement?
If $f(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$ are two differentiable functions on $[a, b],$ and if $\begin{vmatrix}f(t)\quad g(t)\\
f'(t) \quad g'(t)\end{vmatrix}\neq 0,$ for some value of $t\in [a, b],$ then $f(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$ are LI on $[a, b]$

Comment: See here: http://www.ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/204/constantcoeff/linearIndependence.htm

Comment: Try contraposition. If $f(t) = cg(t)$, then we can easily verify that $f(t)g'(t) - g(t)f'(t) = 0$ for all $t \in [a,b]$.

Answer (score 2):

This is linear algebra: if the functions are l.d., then say $\;f(t)=kg(t)\;,\,\,\forall\,t\in[a,b]\;,\;\;k=\,$ constant, and thus

$$W[f,g](t)=f(t)g'(t)-f'(t)g(t)=f(t)(kf'(t))-f'(t)(kf(t))=0$$

I leave it to you to prove that if there is **at least one value** $\;t_0\in[a,b]\;$ s.t. $\;W([f,g](t_0)\neq0\;$ , then a constant $\;k\;$ as above cannot exist and thus $\;f,g\;$ are l.i. on $\;[a,b]\;$ .

Comment: Dear, even if that $t_0=b,$ then what is the meaning of derivative at $b?$ I mean how do we calculate the derivative at the end point of an interval?

Comment: @thomus You've got a point there. In general, the condition on the Wronskian for l.i. of functions which are differential on some interval...and for this reason the interval uses to be open. Anyway, when talking of a closed interval the extreme points are understood to be unimportant for this and we should in fact be taking only the corresponding open one.

Comment: In solving one of the problem, I got the Wronskian at $t=b$ to be non-zero (I assumed the derivative at $t=b$ is nothing but the left hand derivative). So can I conclude that the functions are LI on $[a, b]$ in this case?

Comment: @thomus As already said, the Wronskian condition applies **only** when the functions are differentiable. I'm not sure taking one sided derivatives is enough...